# Pure virtual function definition outside derived class

Tags: c++

I have abstract base class and derived class in header file. Is it possible to have definition of pure virtual function outside the derived class?

For example:

```
//file .h
class Baseclass
{
public:
    virtual int vfunc() = o;
   //assume Ctor and Dctor
};
class Derivedclass : public Baseclass
{
public:
    int vfunc();
    //assume Ctor and Dctor
};
```

Now in the cpp file:

```
#include <file.h>
int Derivedclass :: vfunc()
{
    // Body of the function
}
```

Is the above method correct/possible?

Comment: you should use `#include "file.h"`

Comment: Why did you think it was incorrect ? Did the compiler give any errors or warnings ??

Comment: @elyashiv: No! Please don't give such blanket statements. There is a real difference between `<>` and `""`, if you wish to explain please do, but don't hammer a rule of your own without any justification.

Comment: It's `= 0;` rather than `= o;`

Comment: Sorry, mistake from my side on typo: 1) virtual int vfunc() = 0; 2) #include "file.h". But my main intension was to understand for the method of definition for a pure virtual function. I got clarified from the answers below. Thank you all.

Comment: Question: why do I get error message "'virtual' outside class declaration" if I declare the inherited method virtual in the above example?

Answer (score 3):

This is not only possible, it's standard practice. The only time you have to worry about putting function definitions into the header is with templates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can define them outside your class, if that is what at all you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have definition of pure virtual function outside the derived class?

The function is not pure virtual in the derived class, it's only pure virtual in the base class.

The derived class overrides the function and does not have a pure-specifier (the `=0` bit after the function declarator) so `DerivedClass::vfunc()` is not pure virtual, and therefore *must* have a definition somewhere if it's used in the program.  Defining it in a separate file from the header is perfectly normal.

Comment: Note that the question as written uses `=o` rather than `=0` -- and that `=o` will result in a compiler error, perhaps a rather confusing one.